# Storing PHP includes() into memory

Tags: php, loops, html-table, include

I'm building a dynamic table that will be editable and formatted based on the type of data within. For example, a column with a color, and a column with a rating, and a column with a date.

The data stored in the database is text (#009900 OR 4 OR 1435856109) but the type of information will determine how its displayed and edited. clicking on a color cell opens a color picker, clicking on a date opens a calendar date-picker etc.

To achieve this I would loop through the rows and cells and include ("edit_color.php" OR "edit_date.php") to bring up the proper editor. The problem comes when there are dozens or hundreds of rows with each cell including a separate php file over and over.

Is there a way to include the file once into memory and use the code within over and over without having to include it for every cell loop?

This a basic idea of the code

```
<table>
<?php 
    foreach ($rows as $row){
     echo "<tr>";
     foreach ($cells as $cell){
         echo "<td>";
         include ("/cells/edit_".$cell->type.".php");
         echo "</td>";
     }
    echo "</tr>";
    }
<table>

//edit_date.php\\
<div class="cell_name"><?php echo date("D-M-Y",$cell->data)?></div>
<a href="#" onClick="openCalendar()">Pick Date</a>
```

There's a lot more going on but I don't want to have to include each `edit_[type].php` for every cell. What other options are there?

Comment: Or you could use functions like a *sane person*.

Comment: `Theres a lot more going on but I don't want to have to include each edit_[type].php for every cell. What other options are there?` This should work fine, and is typically easy and performant. If you're running into trouble, it's possible it's a memory leak of some sort in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a function instead.

e.g. you have

foo.php

```
<?php
    echo 'hello from foo';
```

which you include a bajillion times. Instead, have this:

foo.php:

```
<?php

function foo() {
   return 'hello from foo';
}
```

Include this ONCE, and then you call `foo()` wherver you need it:

```
<td><?php echo foo(); ?><</td>
```

Comment: Can the data from an included file be loaded for use within the function call? The reason it matters, is there could be 20 different data types some with complex display/edit rules. Creating a function to handle all the exceptions and rules with a large switch case would be a very long function.

Comment: `include` essentially works as if whatever you're including was literally cut&pasted into the spot you're doing the include.

Comment: Thanks. If I use include in my function, and call my function for every iteration, wouldn't it still include the file anew every time the function is called?

Answer (score 0):

Is this being served as a web app?

If yes, you may want to explore caching the file at the web server level, rather than directly in PHP.

For example, if you're using Apache:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/caching.html

Comment: Once the file is cached, it can be included like any other file but with less server resource use?

Comment: I'm not super well versed on the details of caching various webservers, but that's the general idea.  The disk reads are by far the most expensive part of a typical web request. 

Apache should be smart enough to cache frequently used files in memory automatically, I'm not sure of the implementation details though.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is use include_once().

However, you should never include code in loops like this - it's just very bad form.

You should use include_once AND autoloading... (and separation of presentation and code, but that's too much to explain here).